# Derivation of the second derivative of distance wrt time

Tags: calculus

The formula for the second derivative of distance with respect to time is

$a = \dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{ds}{dt}\right)$

$= \dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2}$   (just the $t$ is squared - it's not $dt$ all squared).

The question is why is $dt$ multiplied by $dt$ equal to $dt^2$ with just the $t$ squared. Why is not the $d$ also squared? As we can see $d . ds$ becomes $d^2 s$.

Apologies for this probably simple question, I am at the beginning of a very long road in maths.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of notation. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I have used LaTeX to make your question more readable.  But you should check that it says what you intended

Comment: Notation is justifiable too, as $ \frac{d^2s}{dt^2} \neq  \frac{1}{\frac{d^2t}{ds^2}}$

Answer (score 2):

I would say that what looks like the denominator in $\dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2}$ represents $dt$ all squared.

Let's suppose you have the following data with constant acceleration and try to calculate it:

```
s   35  75  135  215  315   
t   10  12   14   16   18
```

Take the differences and you get

```
ds    40   60   80  100
dt     2    2    2    2
```

suggesting velocities of $\dfrac{ds}{dt}=20,30,40,50$ measured at intervals $2$ seconds apart

Now take the difference of `ds` to give `d^2 s`, but square `dt` to give `(dt)^2`

```
d^2 s   20   20   20  
(dt)^2   4    4    4
```

suggesting that the acceleration is $\dfrac{20}{4} = 5$.  This is consistent with the original example data for $s$ and $t$, suggesting the $d^2s$ could be understood as the second difference in distance, i.e. $d(ds)$.  It also suggests that the $dt^2$ could be understood as the square of the first difference of time, i.e  $dt$ all squared.

In other cases the acceleration will change with time and you are interested in limits as the time intervals $dt$ tend to zero.  But while taking that limit you are in effect looking at $(dt)^2$ rather than $d(t^2)$ or $(dt)t$

Comment: This is clearer to me now, I am very grateful for your efforts, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Although the notation of derivative $\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{ds}{dt}\right)$ looks like a fraction but it's not a fraction; that's why it doesn't implies $d$ is multiplied by $ds$ and $dt$ is multiplied by $dt$.

$\dfrac{ds}{dt}$ means derivative of $s$ with respect to $t$ and similarly $\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{ds}{dt}\right)$ means derivative of $\dfrac{ds}{dt}$ with respect to $t$.

So the notation for derivative of $\dfrac{ds}{dt}$ with respect to $t$ is $\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{ds}{dt}\right)$ which is also expressed by $\dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2}$.

For more details you can follow the answers of this question: [Is $\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}$ not a ratio?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio)